# No package found with specified pattern in AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the following Azure Pipelines jobs:

```
 - job: Publish
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'
    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: Setup
      inputs:
        packageType: sdk
        version: 3.1.x
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Publish
      inputs:
        command: publish
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: 'src/**/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration staging --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        zipAfterPublish: true
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      displayName: Export
      inputs:
        artifact: 'Staging'
        targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  - deployment: Deploy
    dependsOn: Publish
    pool:
      vmImage: Ubuntu-16.04
    environment: staging
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
            displayName: Import
            inputs:
              artifact: 'Staging'
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            displayName: Api
            inputs:
              connectedServiceName: '$(azure.subscription)'
              webAppKind: 'webApp'
              webAppName: 'bityond-demo-api'
              package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Api.zip'
              removeAdditionalFilesFlag: true
```

When I run the pipeline the following tasks are successful:

1. Setup
2. Publish
3. Export
4. Import

Then on the last task, "Api" - AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4, I get the error:

```
##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: /home/vsts/work/1/a/Api.zip<br/>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.
```

I checked and the artifacts are available and I am able to download them.

And the Import task is successful so what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify destination directory for the imported artifact:

```
   - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
     inputs:
       artifact: 'Staging'
       targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

If not specified, artifacts by defaults are downloaded into $(Pipeline.Workspace) directory that is equal to `/home/vsts/work/1`. And for the `AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4` task you are looking for artifacts at `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` directory (equal to `/home/vsts/work/1/a`)